# Segmentation fault at the very beginning of the method

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, gcc, address-sanitizer

I have been trying to figure out the root cause for a segmentation fault that I see while running my application with Address Sanitizer(ASAN) enabled. When I attach GDB and debug the application, I see the segfault being received right at the beginning of the method:

Minimal code:

```
    int TimerScope::switchMode() {  
        doCapture(mode)
    }

>  int TimerScope::doCapture(Mode captureMode) {  <---- segfault here
       if(handle == -1)
           return 0;

       XLOG(TRACE, image(this));
        ..
    }
```

Note that I don't see the issue for a build without address sanitizer. I have looked at different aspects of this issue (like looking for garbage address of variables, running valgrind/UBSAN etc) without any luck. Currently I am looking into the assembly code to see if there are any clues there. With GDB, when I print the location of the segfault, this is what I get:

```
(gdb) p $_siginfo._sifields._sigfault.si_addr
$5 = (void *) 0x7fe4d3908fb8
```

The assembly code is as given below, which is executing some logic as the method `TimerScope::doCapture` gets called:

```
    0x7fe69595f65e <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE>          endbr64                                                                                        │
│    0x7fe69595f662 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+4>        push   %rbp                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f663 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+5>        mov    %rsp,%rbp                                                                               │
│    0x7fe69595f666 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+8>        push   %r15                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f668 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+10>       push   %r14                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f66a <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+12>       push   %r13                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f66c <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+14>       push   %r12                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f66e <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+16>       push   %rbx                                                                                    │
│    0x7fe69595f66f <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+17>       sub    $0x1000,%rsp                                                                            │
│    0x7fe69595f676 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+24>       orq    $0x0,(%rsp)                                                                             │
│    0x7fe69595f67b <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+29>       sub    $0x1a8,%rsp                                                                             │
│  > 0x7fe69595f682 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+36>       mov    %rdi,-0x1198(%rbp)                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f689 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+43>       mov    %esi,%eax                                                                               │
│    0x7fe69595f68b <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+45>       mov    %al,-0x119c(%rbp)                                                                       │
│    0x7fe69595f691 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+51>       lea    -0x1170(%rbp),%rax                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f698 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+58>       mov    %rax,-0x11a8(%rbp)                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f69f <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+65>       mov    %rax,-0x11c0(%rbp)                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f6a6 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+72>       mov    0x7b92943(%rip),%rax        # 0x7fe69d4f1ff0                                            │
│    0x7fe69595f6ad <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+79>       cmpl   $0x0,(%rax)                                                                             │
│    0x7fe69595f6b0 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+82>       je     0x7fe69595f6c8 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+106>                      │
│    0x7fe69595f6b2 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+84>       mov    $0x1120,%edi                                                                            │
│    0x7fe69595f6b7 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+89>       call   0x7fe6952d6510 <__asan_stack_malloc_7@plt>                                              │
│    0x7fe69595f6bc <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+94>       test   %rax,%rax                                                                               │
│    0x7fe69595f6bf <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+97>       je     0x7fe69595f6c8 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+106>                      │
│    0x7fe69595f6c1 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+99>       mov    %rax,-0x11a8(%rbp)                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f6c8 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+106>      mov    -0x11a8(%rbp),%rbx                                                                      │
│    0x7fe69595f6cf <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+113>      lea    0x1140(%rbx),%rax
```

In particular, following is the line that segfaults:

```
0x7fe69595f682 <_ZN7ts9TimerScope9doCaptureENS_8ModeE+36>       mov    %rdi,-0x1198(%rbp)
```

What could be the logic being executed here? I can see that the value of register `rbp` is `0x7fe4d390a150` and the faulting address `0x7fe4d3908fb8` can be obtained by subtracting `0x1198` from `0x7fe4d390a150`. Why would the address `0x7fe4d3908fb8` cause a segfault?

Below is the frame info:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fe4d390a160:
 rip = 0x7fe69595f682 in ts::TimerScope::doCapture (/tsmgr/src/TimerScope.cpp:142);
    saved rip = 0x7fe69595ec93
 called by frame at 0x7fe4d390a540
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7fe4d390a150, args: this=0x0, mode=ts::Mode::None
 Locals at 0x7fe4d390a150, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fe4d390a160
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7fe4d390a128, rbp at 0x7fe4d390a150, r12 at 0x7fe4d390a130, r13 at 0x7fe4d390a138, r14 at 0x7fe4d390a140, r15 at 0x7fe4d390a148, rip at 0x7fe4d390a158
```

Another thing strange is if I detach the debugger at this point, the error message printed for the segfault shows a different faulting address (0x3e95c1f300086ab5):

```
*** Aborted at 1659061552 (Unix time, try 'date -d @1659061552') ***
*** Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) (0x3e95c1f300086ab5) received by PID 551605 (pthread TID 0x7fbe64166700) (linux TID 551964) (maybe from PID 551605, UID 1050001907) (code: -6), stack trace: ***
```

ASAN also reports the same address:

```
==551605==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x3e95c1f300086ab5 (pc 0x7fbf388386c4 bp 0x7fbe64128100 sp 0x7fbe641260d8 T358)
==551605==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
```

Why would GDB be reporting a different faulting address than what is printed by signal handler, ASAN?

In the backtrace seen upon segfault, `this` and `mode` are yet to be set after the method call (hence they are showing different values from that in frame #1):

```
#0  0x00007fe69595f682 in ts::TimerScope::doCapture(this=0x0, mode=ts::Mode::None)
    at /tsmgr/src/TimerScope.cpp:142
#1  0x00007fe69595ec93 in ts::TimerScope::switchMode(this=0x612002750d40, mode=ts::Mode::Exclusive)
    at /tsmgr/src/TimerScope.cpp:132
#2  0x00007fe6993b2c2b in ts::DataTimer::switchMode(this=0x6040021ac4e0, mode=ts::Mode::Exclusive)
    at /tsmgr/src/DataTimer.hpp:84
#3  0x00007fe6993c47c6 in ts::DataTimerScope::switchMode(this=0x6030037d13d0, mode=ts::Mode::Exclusive)
    at /tsmgr/src/DataTimerScope.cpp:49
#4  0x00007fe698e0a02a in ts::DataEntry::changeTimerMode (this=0x7fe29ba72700, mode=ts::Mode::Exclusive)
```

I am using gcc/g++-10 with libasan6 support to build the application, running it on ubuntu 20.04 environment.

Have been able to provide just the snippets of code as there is a lot of other logic which would be hard to present in a sensible manner. Any pointers on how to further approach the issue would be helpful. Would keep updating the question as more information is asked for.

---

Edit #1:
At the point of segfault, the difference between stack pointers in frame 0 and that in the base of the stack (frame 76) is 199568 bytes. The stack space size is set to 8M (default)

For the faulting address:

```
(gdb) p $_siginfo._sifields._sigfault.si_addr
$2 = (void *) 0x7f442a630c68
```

And `rbp` pointing to `0x7f442a632150`

Using `info proc mappings`, I see following addresses that match:

```
  0x7f4429e71000     0x7f442a631000   0x7c0000        0x0
  0x7f442a631000     0x7f442a671000    0x40000        0x0
```

Comment: Have been debugging this issue for days now. Would really appreciate any ideas on how to further approach this issue.

Comment: `int TimerScope::doCapture(Mode captureMode)` -- 1) `TimerScope` may be an invalid object instance 2) `Mode` is passed by value, requiring it to have correct copy semantics.

Comment: And to be honest, personally I rarely, if ever, need to look at assembly code to figure out why a C++ program crashes.  A good debugging session and visually looking at the C++ code is what is required.  The problem is that if a person doesn't have enough C++ experience to know what to look for, then they will never find the issue by looking at the source code.

Comment: `Arglist at 0x7fe4d390a150, args: this=0x0, mode=ts::Mode::None` -- Look closely at `this=0x0`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1. Notice that `doCapture` is being called from another member of class `TimerScope`. I have inspected the instance as well using GDB and didn't see any garbage addresses there. 2. `Mode` is an enumeration. Other strange thing is I am not seeing this issue unless I build the application with Address Sanitizer.

Comment: *didn't see any garbage addresses there* -- You cannot determine if an address is "garbage" by looking at the value.  C++ doesn't work that way.  You can have a perfectly "good looking" address, and it could still be invalid.  `int *ptr = new int;  delete ptr; *ptr = 1;` -- That is an example.

Comment: `this=0x0` can be ignored, segfault is at the very beginning of the method call where `this` is yet to be set. This method gets called several times before where it doesn't segfault. In those other cases, if I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and then step into the code, I do see that `this` eventually gets set. Also, I have verified in the `switchMode` method (frame 1 of when it segfaults) that `this` is a valid instance.

Comment: I'll repeat -- *The problem is that if a person doesn't have enough C++ experience to know what to look for, then they will never find the issue by looking at the source code.* -- Unless you post a [mcve], I don't know what else to tell you.  Maybe the issue would be obvious *if someone else were to look at the code with C++ experience*, and you're totally missing the issue because in your eyes, everything looks ok.

Comment: Is this running in a thread? Do you have enough stack? Maybe a recursion problem?

Comment: I'm only spitballing stack because there is a stack probe of the next 4kiB page that seems to work but access to the next 4KiB page below that seems to fail with writing to -0x1198(%rbp)

Comment: What is the output of `bt`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I can make the segfault go away if I comment out the `XLOG` and everything below it in `TimerScope::doCapture`. If I break at the exact same place after commenting those lines, I see that the assembly code that otherwise caused segfault now shows `mov    %rdi,-0x368(%rbp)` instead and application just runs fine. However, if I uncomment just the XLOG line and run again, segfault would again show up, which is strange. 
Yes, it is possible that it has something to do with access beyond the 4KiB page.

Comment: @kiner_shah Added first few frames of the backtrace.

Comment: Really sounds like you run out of stack space now because what changed is the number of local variables.

Comment: @CherryDT There is no recursive function call here, I also have several gigs of memory available at the point of segfault. But please let me know if there is anything else that can cause the program to run out of stack space.

Comment: If this is Linux the default stack size may be 8MiB or less (no matter what your available RAM is). If this is Linux what does `ulimit -all` show as output? If Linux you may be able to try increasing stack size with `ulimit -s 65536` to 64MiB to see what happens. If this is stack space you would be putting an awful lot of data on the stack.

Comment: Show the definition of `XLOG`.

Comment: And if it may be all stack related you mention you use Valgrind. You could profile your program and its stack usage with `valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes ./nameofprogram` . This will of course slow things down, but might provide useful info.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Thanks for the suggestion. I was hopeful that it could be an issue related to stack space and did try with ulimit -s 32768 (anything beyond that was showing as *not permissible*), unfortunately though it didn't fix the issue. I also checked the stack pointer of the last frame and it points to `0x7f21f9dbe7c8` and a diff with stack pointer from frame 0 (0x7f21f9d8f160) is around 194152 bytes (which I think suggests that 8M stack size should also be OK).

Comment: @j6t: It is the folly logging library: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/logging/docs/Overview.md

Comment: frame `0` is just the previous call; GDB numbers frames up from 0, with 0 being the current.  So your `199568` byte usage is just in the last function call, not total stack space usage.  Check `info proc mappings` to see the size of the actual stack region, and how close your pointers are to the bottom of it.  (The mapping grows downward up to 8MiB.)

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, the diff is actually between the `sp` in frame 0 vs that in frame 76 (last frame). I have updated the question with what I see from `info proc mappings`. Please let me know if you find something noteworthy there.

Comment: Oh, does your GDB not have lines like `0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]` in the `info proc mappings` output that make it easy to find the main thread's stack?  Or is that a thread stack that you're looking at.

Comment: `0x7f442a630c68` is just below the bottom of one mapping, into another.  Your GDB doesn't show info other than size/start/end, but the `0x7f4429e71000     0x7f442a631000` range might be write protected guard pages below the stack.  Clearly it's not writeable, since that faulted.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, I find that mprotect was being called in the code base with stack size set to 256K. I bumped that to 1024K and it just worked. Will soon update the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I also use AddressSanitizer builds in a multithread application. I also had some cases where the AddressSanitizer builds create segmentation fault in code that ware fine. So in my case the the root of the segfaults was to small stack size on specific threads.

The AddressSanitizer builds needs sometimes up to 3x times more stack memory.

Here are all limitation for the clang compiler: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#limitations

Comment: Yeah, this pretty much has to be it.  The program faults on a `mov %rdi,-0x1198(%rbp)` store to stack space, in a function that set up RBP as a frame pointer.  And earlier `push` instructions didn't fault.  Unless some bug in the program led to an `munmap` or `mprotect` of a page of stack space?  Anyway, that store is a page lower than previous stores to stack memory, as Michael Petch commented under the question, so that's exactly where you'd expect a fault if you entered the function with RSP pointing into the last valid stack page at the bottom of the 8MiB region.

Comment: Checking `/proc/<PID>/maps` could confirm the range of stack addresses.  (Or in GDB, `info proc mappings`)